# i cant seem to find the syntaxerror in setup and draw in this flowfield sketch

Tags: java, processing

this is my first post on stackoverflow and I am also quite new to Java, I made a sketch in processing 4.3, (first in python mode, which did actually work, then i made this Java version) that generates a flowfield based on Perlin noise, however whenever i try to run my sketch, i get a syntaxerror: "missing operator, semicolon or '}' near draw()" (the squiggly line also appears under setup ).
Could anyone help me find the error, and maybe even help with some improvements to my code?
Thanks in advance

```
final int particlecount;
final float dz, resolution, flowstrength;


//amount of particles, most performance heavy, up until 10k renders at a reasonable rate on my machine
particlecount = 1000;
//variation in noisefield, higher means more zoomed in
resolution = 5;
//speed in variation of noisefield, increment of z-axis, higher means slower
dz = 1;
//speed of particles, higher means faster, but makes uglier sketches
flowstrength = 5;


public class Particle {
  public float x, y;//position
  public float dx, dy;//speed
  public float px, py;//for drawing lines and calculating angle
  public float angle, hue;//color variables


  public Particle(float part_x, float part_y) {
    this.x = part_x;
    this.y = part_y;
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.px = x;
    this.py = y;
    this.angle=0;
    this.hue=0;
  }

  public void updatevel(float newdx, float newdy) {
    this.dx = newdx;
    this.dy = newdy;
  }

  //looparound
  public void edges(boolean doLoopover) {
    if (doLoopover == true) {
      if (this.x <= 0) {
        this.x = width;
      }
      if (this.y <= 0) {
        this.y = height;
      }

      if (this.y >= height) {
        this.y = 0;
      }
      if (this.x >= width) {
        this.x = 0;
      }
      //else just pick a random position
    } else {
      if (this.x <= 0 || this.y <= 0 || this.x >= width || this.y >= height) {
        this.x = random(width);
        this.y = random(height);
      }
    }
  }

  public void show(int alpha) {
    float deltax = this.x - this.px;
    float deltay = this.y - this.py;
    this.angle = atan2(deltay, deltax);

    //map vertical direction to a brightness value; the more positive, the brighter
    float bright = map(sin(this.angle), -1, 1, 0, 100);

    push();
    colorMode(HSB);
    stroke(this.hue, 0, bright, alpha);

    //only draw non-looparound steps
    if (dist(this.x, this.y, this.px, this.py) < flowstrength * 2) {
      beginShape();
      vertex(this.x, this.y);
      vertex(this.px, this.py);
      endShape();
    }
    //point(this.x, this.y);
    pop();
  }


  public void move() {
    this.px = this.x;
    this.x += this.dx;

    this.py = this.y;
    this.y += this.dy;
  }
}



public class NoiseField {
  float resolution, z, dz;

  public NoiseField(float intresolution, float intdz) {
    this.resolution = pow(intresolution, -3);
    this.dz = pow(intdz, -1);
    this.z = 0;
  }
  //generate noise value at position, optional noise-angle
  public float getnoise(float posx, float posy, boolean returnangle) {
    float xval = this.resolution * posx;
    float yval = this.resolution * posy;
    calnoise = noise(xval, yval, this.z);
    if (returnangle == true) {
      return calnoise * TWO_PI;
    } else {
      return calnoise;
    }
  }
  //increment the z-axis
  public void tick() {
    this.z += this.dz;
  }


  public void resetZ() {
    this.z = 0;
  }
}


Particle[] particleList;
particleList = new Particle[particlecount];

//initialise noise field
noisefield = Noisefield(resolution, dz);

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  colorMode(RGB);
  background(40);
  stroke(5);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();

  for (int i = 0; i < particlecount; i++) {
    Particle newparticle = new Particle(random(width), random(height) );
    particleList[i] = newparticle;
  }
}


void draw() {
  colorMode(RGB);
  background(20);


  for (int i = 0; i < particlecount; i++) {
    //access current particle and calculate its velocity based on its position in the flowfield
    Particle currentparticle = particleList[i];
    paticlenoise = noisefield.getnoise(currentparticle.x, currentparticle.y, true);
    float xvel = flowstrength * cos(particlenoise);
    float yvel = flowstrength * sin(particlenoise);

    currentparticle.updatevel(xvel, yvel);
    currentparticle.move();
    //do looparound
    currentparticle.edges(true);
    currentparticle.show(50);
  }

  //saveFrame("frames/flowfield_####.png");
  push();
  fill(40);
  rect(5, 0, 30, 20);
  fill(200);
  text(frameCount, 10, 10);
  pop();
  noisefield.tick();
}
```

I looked through my whole code, and checked for semicolons and correctly matched brackets etc. but nothing seemed wrong, i also previously had variables for the canvas size and i read that processing doesn't like you doing that so i just hardcoded the canvas size

Comment: What does "made a program in processing" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i did miss some type declarations, `calnoise = noise(xval, yval, this.z);` missed a `float`, `noisefield = Noisefield(resolution, dz);` missed `Noisefield` and `paticlenoise = noisefield.getnoise(currentparticle.x, currentparticle.y, true);` had a spelling mistake.

this is my now working code:

```
//speed in variation of noisefield, increment of z-axis, higher means slower
final float dz = 1;
//variation in noisefield, higher means more zoomed in
final float resolution = 6;
//speed of particles, higher means faster, but makes uglier sketches
final float flowstrength = 1;
//amount of particles, most performance heavy, up until 10k renders at a reasonable rate on my machine
final int particlecount = 10000;

//initialise list of particles
Particle[] particleList = new Particle[particlecount];



public class Particle {
  public float x, y;//position
  public float dx, dy;//speed
  public float px, py;//for drawing lines and calculating angle
  public float angle, hue;//color variables


  public Particle(float part_x, float part_y) {
    this.x = part_x;
    this.y = part_y;
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.px = x;
    this.py = y;
    this.angle=0;
    this.hue=0;
  }

  public void updatevel(float newdx, float newdy) {
    this.dx = newdx;
    this.dy = newdy;
  }

  //looparound
  public void edges(boolean doLoopover) {
    if (doLoopover == true) {
      if (this.x < 0) {
        this.x = width;
      }
      if (this.y < 0) {
        this.y = height;
      }

      if (this.y > height) {
        this.y = 0;
      }
      if (this.x > width) {
        this.x = 0;
      }
      //else just pick a random position
    } else {
      if (this.x <= 0 || this.y <= 0 || this.x >= width || this.y >= height) {
        this.x = random(width);
        this.y = random(height);
      }
    }
  }

  public void show(int alpha) {


    //map vertical direction to a brightness value; the more positive, the brighter

    push();
    colorMode(HSB);
    stroke(0, 0, 100, alpha);

    //only draw non-looparound steps
    if (dist(this.x, this.y, this.px, this.py) < flowstrength * 2) {
      beginShape();
      vertex(this.x, this.y);
      vertex(this.px, this.py);
      endShape();
    }
    //point(this.x, this.y);
    pop();
  }


  public void move() {
    this.px = this.x;
    this.x += this.dx;

    this.py = this.y;
    this.y += this.dy;
  }
}



public class NoiseField {
  float resolution, z, dz;

  public NoiseField(float intresolution, float intdz) {
    this.resolution = pow(intresolution, -3);
    this.dz = pow(intdz, -1);
    this.z = 0;
  }
  //generate noise value at position, optional noise-angle
  public float getnoise(float posx, float posy, boolean returnangle) {
    float xval = this.resolution * posx;
    float yval = this.resolution * posy;
    float calcnoise = noise(xval, yval, this.z);

    if (returnangle == true) {
      return calcnoise * TWO_PI;
    } else {
      return calcnoise;
    }
  }
  //increment the z-axis
  public void tick() {
    this.z += this.dz;
  }


  public void resetZ() {
    this.z = 0;
  }
}
NoiseField noisefield = new NoiseField(resolution, dz);
void setup() {


  size(1920, 1080);
  colorMode(RGB);
  background(40);
  stroke(5);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();

  for (int i = 0; i < particlecount; i++) {
    Particle newparticle = new Particle(random(width), random(height) );
    particleList[i] = newparticle;
  }
}

void draw() {
  colorMode(RGB);
  background(0);


  for (int i = 0; i < particlecount; i++) {
    //access current particle and calculate its velocity based on its position in the flowfield
    Particle currentparticle = particleList[i];
    float particlenoise = noisefield.getnoise(currentparticle.x, currentparticle.y, true);
    float xvel = flowstrength * cos(particlenoise);
    float yvel = flowstrength * sin(particlenoise);

    currentparticle.updatevel(xvel, yvel);
    currentparticle.move();
    //do looparound
    currentparticle.edges(true);
    currentparticle.show(200);
  }

  //saveFrame("frames/flowfield_####.png");
  push();
  fill(40);
  rect(5, 0, 30, 20);
  fill(200);
  text(frameCount, 10, 10);
  pop();
  //noisefield.tick();
}
```